# PHP array intersect (sort of)

Tags: php, arrays

Given two arrays:

```
$foo = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$bar = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
```

Is there a built-in PHP function to produce the following result array?

```
$result = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
```

I've been through the [Array Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) list on php.net, but can't seem to find what I'm looking for.  I know how to do it myself if need be, but I figured this might be a common-enough problem that there might be a built-in function that does it and didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Basically pull out the key/val pairs from $bar where bar's keys have a matching value in $foo?

Comment: To Clarify : So you want to extract the values from the second array that have keys that match the first array ?

Comment: Yes, I want a resulting array that has the elements from the second array (`$bar`), but only the keys from the first array (`$foo`).

Comment: And you know how to accomplish this with a simple iteration, you just want to know if there's a specific array function to handle it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way using [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) and [array_intersect_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php):

```
$foo = array('a', 'b', 'c'); 
$bar = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

$common = array_intersect_key($bar, array_flip($foo));
```

**Output**

```
array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  int(0)
  ["b"]=>
  int(1)
  ["c"]=>
  int(2)
}
```

Comment: reverse the order of arguments to array_intersect_key() to maintain the values from the original $bar array

Comment: @Mark Baker. Good call! Thanks.

Comment: This is very similar to the solution I posted, but I'm picking it because of your use of `array_flip($foo)` over my use of `array_fill_keys($foo, NULL)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a dirty hack, but it works:

```
function extractKeys($keys, $data) {
    extract($data);

    return call_user_func_array('compact', $keys);
}

$foo = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$bar = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

var_dump(extractKeys($foo, $bar));
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  int(1)
  ["b"]=>
  int(2)
  ["c"]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After posting, I thought of one way of doing this:

```
array_intersect_key($bar, array_fill_keys($foo, NULL))
```

Though, this isn't really the concise, built-in function that I had hoped for, it's definitely better than constructing the resultant array manually.

Comment: array_fill_keys($foo, NULL) can be replaced with array_flip($foo)

Comment: @MarkBaker: I had never thought of using `array_flip()` on a non-associative array. That's a neat trick, thanks.

Comment: best type of array to use it on.... no risk of duplicate values leading to overwriting keys when it's flipped